# How to write a functional test case in rails 3.1 and unit:test

Tags: unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-3.1, functional-testing, assertion, minitest

i am new to rails testing and i am using unit:test. I have an action in my controller

```
   def save_campaign
      unless params[:app_id].blank?
        @app = TestApp.find(params[:app_id])
          if params[:test_app]
            @app.update_attributes(params[:test_app])
           end
        flash[:notice] = "Your Registration Process is completed"
       redirect_to "/dashboard"
      else
    redirect_to root_path
     end
    end
```

and my test case is as following

```
test "should save campagin " do
 assert_difference('TestApp.count', 0) do
           post :save_campaign,    test_app: @test_app.attributes
        end
       assert_redirected_to "/dashboard"
      end
   end
```

This method is a post method. While running this test, it is failing and showing me a message

> "should save campagin  (0.07s) 
>             Expected response to be a redirect to http://test.host/dashboard but was a redirect to http://test.host/
>             /home/nouman/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib/action_dispatch/testing/assertions/response.rb:67:in `assert_redirected_to'

My guess is that i am not giving it right assertion to check params

> params[:app_id] and  @app = TestApp.find(params[:app_id]).

How can i write such an assertion to check these attributes, check wether a parameter is blank. How can 1 find an object with a given id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For functional test, you should not care about testing the model, that is in your case, you should remove:

```
assert_difference('TestApp.count', 0) do
..
end
```

What you want to know in a functional test is that if the page is loaded, redirected correctly.

In your controller, you have a condition check for params, so for each of the outcome of the check, you write a test each, that is you have to write two functional tests:

```
test "if app_id param is empty, #save_campaign redirect to root" do
  post :save_campaign, :app_id => nil
  assert_redirected_to root_path
end

test "#save_campaign" do
  post :save_campaign, :app_id => app_fixture_id, :test_app => @test_app.attributes.to_params
  assert_redirected_to '/dashboard'
end
```

The trick to prepare the post params is to use method `to_params` method.

Hope this help.

**UPDATE:** If you just want to check if `params[:app_id]` GET param is in the URL, you should just check for this presence instead of checking if it is blank or not:

```
if params[:app_id]

else

end
```

Comment: Thanks Trung for the answer, sorry i was not aware of your response that's why accepting it after few months.